# Creating a multi selectable custom ListView

Tags: android

I am trying to modify my ListView so that it:

1. Contains an image
2. Contains a text description (fileName)
3. Contains a check box.

The list should be multi selectable.  And I should be able to loop through all the checked checkboxes and get the description.

Currently, I can display an ordinary ListView with check boxes.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HelloDropboxActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,fileName);
                mTestListOutput.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                mTestListOutput.setAdapter(ad);
```

Using the onClick of a `Button` - I can loop through the checked boxes and get the text into an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<String> dbLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
 int cntChoice = mTestListOutput.getCount();
  SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = mTestListOutput.getCheckedItemPositions();

                for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++)
                {
                    if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true)
                    {

                        dbLinks.add(mTestListOutput.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                    }
                }
```

I am retreving an ArrayList of :
private ArrayList paths;

So how can I tie these together to create a custom ListView?
I have looked at many examples and tried to modify them but I am getting nowhere.

Here I have attampted to create the Layout of a list row in my list_row.xnl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

 <!-- File Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filename"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem that are having is that when the listitem is selected, it is actually being selected but you can't see any difference because the root view must implement 'Checkable'. There is way to make this work although its more complicated that I think it should be.

First of all, you need to add a the following class. This is a checkable LinearLayout that should relay the calls from the checkable interface through to the checkbox within it. It should be easy to modify this for whatever view group you want to use.

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
private CheckBox _checkbox;

public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    // find checked text view
    int childCount = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
        View v = getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof CheckBox) {
            _checkbox = (CheckBox) v;
        }
    }
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return _checkbox != null ? _checkbox.isChecked() : false;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    if (_checkbox != null) {
        _checkbox.setChecked(checked);
    }
}

public void toggle() {
    if (_checkbox != null) {
        _checkbox.toggle();
    }
}
}
```

Next define the layout of that you want to use for each item, using the CheckableLinearLayout above:

```
<com.myPackage.CheckableLinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/background_iv" />

</com.myPackage.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

Then, alter the line that creates the Adapter so that the ID of the layout above is used instead.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this - but what is private CheckedTextReadventureView _checkbox;, and how can I change my code to use it? and where is _checkbox.isChecked() defined?

Comment: Thats a custom checkbox of mine, I didn't notice that when I copied the code over. Altered the answer now so that it uses a standard checkbox.

Comment: thanks - do I need to change this also in the xml to be my package, e.g. <com.myPackage.CheckableLinearLayout to <com.myname.myappname.CheckableLinearLayout  as I am getting the following error:  Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- com.myname.myappname..CheckableLinearLayout (Fix Build Path, Create Class)

Comment: yes you need to update that with the full package name for your app.

Comment: Thanks but I did that already and got the error above in android studio..will make sure I have typed it correctly tomorrow

Comment: Sorry, only half read your comment. In the error message there are two dots in between appname and Checkable, not sure if thats the error or just a mistake when you copied over to here

Comment: Hopefully that's it, I'm away from computer so will check in the morning. I assume I can loop though the list and get checked items? Many thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks that was the issue - it creates the custom listview ok.  But I have two problems now.  The OnClickListener of the ListView is not working.       And I cannot iterate through the ListView and get the checked item:              SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();

                for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++)
                {
                    if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true)
                    {

                        mListView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    }
                }

Comment: The click on the listview might be being swallowed by one of the controls inside the row. If you add 'android:focusable="false"' to the child views it should start working. I've added it to the main answer.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reponse - I am trying this now.  How can I loop through and get the ListItems which are checked? Will this change allow this?

Comment: It worked in that the onItemClick Listener is called!

Comment: It is failing though with at this line: String filename = (String) lstView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();  The position is correct, but it is not returning the text on the ListView. java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I have opened a new question which you may be able to answer, I don't know how to get the checked items (and the text at the checked items).  Here is the new question:      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866930/custom-listview-with-checkbox-how-to-get-selected-items